# Custom spring scopes?

Tags: java, spring

Anyone know of any other custom spring scopes than [Servlet Context Scope](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/custom-servlet-context-scope-module.html) and [ThreadScope](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/custom-thread-scope-module.html) ?

If you've made some closed-source custom scope I'd really also be interested in hearing what it does and how it worked out for you. (I'd imagine someone would make a WindowScope in a desktop app ?)

I'm open to all use cases, I'm looking to expand my horizon here.

Answer (score 10):

We implemented our own custom Spring scope.  A lot of our code works at a relatively low level, close to the database, and we maintain a conceptual level on top of that with its own object model of data sources, links, attributes etc.

Anyway, a lot of beans require a so-called StorageDictionary (an encapsulation of this object graph) to do their work.  When we make non-trivial changes to the object graph, the dictionary sometimes needs to be blown away and recreated.  Consequently, we implemented a custom scope for objects that were *dictionary scoped*, and part of the invalidation of a given dictionary involves clearing this custom scope.  This lets Spring handle a nice form of automatic caching for these objects.  You get the same object back every time up until the dictionary is invalidated, at which point you get a new object.

This helps not only with consistency but also allows the objects themselves to cache references to entities within the dictionary, safe within the knowledge that the cache will be valid for as long as they themselves are retrievable by Spring.  This in turn lets us build these as immutable objects (so long as they can be wired via constructor injection), which is a very good thing to do anyway wherever possible.

This technique won't work everywhere and does depend heavily on the characteristics of the software (e.g. if the dictionary was modified regularly this would be horribly inefficient, and if it was updated never this would be unnecessary and slightly less efficient than direct access).  However, it has definitely helped us pass off this management of lifecycle to Spring in a way that is conceptually straightforward and in my opinion quite elegant.

Comment: Really cool, you expanded my horizon there. I see a "cached" scope or similar. Probably also nice for calculated derived data, which is what it seems like you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

In my company we've created two custom scopes, one that will use Thread or Request and another that will use either Thread or Session.  The idea is that a single scope can be used for scoped beans without having to change configuration based on the execution environment (JUnit or Servlet container).  This also really comes in handy for when you run items in Quartz and no longer have a Request or Session scope available.

Comment: We solved this by using mock session/request objects in the JUnit context instead, so we have request/session scope avilable. Would these two solutions be functionally equivalent ?  (Could probably be used in the quartz scope too ...)

Comment: For the differences between JUnit and the Servlet context, I definitely think they're equivalent.  For Quartz, I think it's a bit more complicated.  If you are injecting scoped beans into your services and trying to call those services from a Quartz job, it would be difficult to workaround that.

Comment: I've no experience with quartz, but does it run in a single thread or different threads?

Comment: To be precise, we have our own ContextLoader that registers the scopes request and session for unit tests. The implementations of these scopes is based on the spring versions of these scopes. Couldn't this approach be used for quartz ?

Answer (score 4):

Background:

I work on a single web app that runs 4 different web sites under the same servlet context.  Each site has its own domain name, e.g. www.examplesite1.com, www.examplesite2.com, etc.

Problem:

Sites sometimes require their own customised instance of a bean from the app context (usually for customised display of messages or formatting of objects).

For example, say sites 1 and 2 both use the "standardDateFormatter" bean, site 3 uses the "usDateFormatter" bean and site 4 uses the "ukDateFormatter" bean.

Solution:

I'm planning on using a "site" scope.

We have a Site enum like this:

```
enum Site {
    SITE1, SITE2, SITE3, SITE4;
}
```

Then we have a filter that stores one of these Site values in the request's thread using a ThreadLocal.  This is the site scope's "conversation id".

Then in the app context there'd be a bean named "dateFormatter", with 'scope="site"'.  Then, wherever we want to use a date formatter, the correct one for the user's current site will be used.

**Added later:**

Sample code here:

http://github.com/eliotsykes/spring-site-scope

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/coherence/index.html) has implemented a [datagrid scope for Spring beans](http://wiki.tangosol.com/display/INCUBATOR/Data+Grid+Beans).  To sum it up:

> A **Data Grid Bean** is a proxy to a
>   java.io.Serializable Bean instance
>   that is stored in a non-expiring
>   Coherence Distributed Cache (called
>   near-datagridbeans).

Never used them myself but they seem cool.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Orchestra provides [SpringConversationScope](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/myfaces-orchestra-core/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/orchestra/conversation/spring/SpringConversationScope.html).

Answer (score 1):

In a Spring Batch application, we have implemented an **item scope**.

#### Background

We have lots of `@Service` components which compute something based on the current batch item. Many of them need the same workflow:

1. Determine relevant item parts.
2. Init stuff based on the item.
3. For each item part, compute something (using stuff).

We moved the workflow into a base class template method, so the subclasses implement only `findItemParts(Item)` (doing 1 and 2) and `computeSomething(ItemPart)` (doing 3). So they became stateful (stuff initialized in `findItemParts` is needed in `computeSomething`), and that state must be cleared before the next item.

Some of those services also involve injected Spring beans which are also derived from the current item and must be removed afterwards.

#### Design

We implemented an `AbstractScopeRegisteringItemProcessor` which registers the item and allows subclasses to register derived beans. At the end of its `process` method, it removes the item from its scope context, and the derived beans using `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton`.

#### How it worked out

It works, but has the following problems:

1. We did not manage to get the derived beans cleaned up without registration (just based on their `@Scope`). The concrete processor must create and register them.
2. `AbstractScopeRegisteringItemProcessor` would have been nicer using composition and dynamically implementing all interfaces of the underlying processor. But then the resulting `@StepScope` bean is a proxy for the [declared return type](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2169) (i.e. `AbstractScopeRegisteringItemProcessor` or `ItemProcessor`) without the required callback interfaces.

### EDIT

With the aid of @Eliot Sykes's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/971703/2099362) and shared code plus @Cheetah's [BeanDefinition registration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25673878/2099362%20BeanDefinition%20registration), I was able to get rid of the registration as singleton beans. Instead, `ItemScopeContext` (the storage used by both the processor and the `Scope` implementation; Java-configured via a static `@Bean` method) implements `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`. It registers a `FactoryBean` whose `getObject()` returns the current item or throws an exception if there is none. Now, a `@Component` annotated with `@Scope(scopeName = "Item", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` can simply inject the item and need not be registered for end-of-scope cleanup.

So in the end, it did work out well.

Answer (score 0):

A spring locale scope based on the users locale wihtin a web application

See [related wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/utils-apl-derived/wiki/LocaleBeanScope)

Answer (score 0):

In my company, we have also implemented spring custom scope. We have a multi tenant system where every customer can customize settings. **Instance** based scope of ours, caches the beans which are customer specific. So each time user of a customer logs in, these settings are cached and reused again when other users of the same customers sign in.

Answer (score 0):

I once used a kind of *conversation scope* to store some objects in the session scope, in order to keep them when re-entering the same page, but limited to a single page to avoid to leave useless objects in the session. The implementation just stored the page URL and cleaned the *conversation scope* on each page change.