# Customizable @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, autowired

Let's assume I have an annotated bean property setter like this:

```
public class Foo {
  ...
  @Autowired 
  public void setBar(Bar bar) {
    ...
}
```

The Springframework will lookup the matching `Bar` property as usual. However, I'd like to intercept the default bean resolving process and add a little bit of "magic" myself. I'd like to introduce a resolver like this:

```
public interface SomeResolverInterface<T> {
  public T resolve(Class<T> beanClass);
}

public class BarResolver implements SomeResolverInterface<Bar> {

  @Override
  public Bar resolve(Class<Bar> beanClass) {
    if(someCondition) {
      return someBean;
    } else {
      return anotherBean;
    }
  }

  ...
```

I know I could alway introduce some kind of wrapper bean and move the resolving logic into this but I'd prefer a more generic way using a resolver like described above to make `Foo` completely independent of the resolving logic.

Is there a way within the Springframework to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description it looks like you only need to perform additional logic at startup time (autowiring). There are several ways to tackle this problem (from worst to best):

- AOP - bad idea, introduces runtime overhead by intercepting every call
- custom scope - see: [Custom spring scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450557) Also works at runtime and also a bad idea
- [`@Profile`](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) - define two matching beans and enable only one based on active profile. Pretty clean and introduces overhead only at startup time
- `@Configuration` - defining beans in Java has an extra benefit of having full control over how are they created:

---

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private Bar someBean;

    @Autowired
    private Bar anotherBean;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Bar primaryBean() {
        if(someCondition) {
          return someBean;
        } else {
          return anotherBean;
        }
      }

}
```

As you can see in this case we have three beans of `Bar` type: `someBean`, `anotherBean` and `primaryBean`. The first two can also be configured using `@Bean` or via component scan with `@Service`. But to make autowiring possible the last `primaryBean` is marked as `@Primary`. This way it will be preferred over other two.

This is my recommended solution as the resolving logic is clean, maintainable and readable. IMHO this is the situation where Java-based `@Configuration` really shines.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the `@Configuration` option provided by Tomasz, you can use a simple `FactoryBean`. Just implement the interface, and declare the factory bean. In the `getObject()` method perform your custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never tried this I think you could look at plugging your logic via

```
AnnotationConfigUtils
```

Or look at

```
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
```

and see if it allows for simple extension/pluggability of your logic