# How to programatically register an instance of a FactoryBean in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a set of instances of `FactoryBean` which are of type `MyFactoryBean`. The constructor takes a `Class<?>` and uses that to determine what to return from `getObject()`:

```
public class MyFactoryBean implements FactoryBean {

    private final Class<?> type;

    public MyFactoryBean(Class<?> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject() throws Exception {
        return null; // Obviously I return something here rather than null!
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My end result is to control what is returned when an instance of type passed to the constructor of the `MyFactoryBean` is requested from the context.

I can register them with my context like this:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(..., ...);
```

But it doesn't feel right, and autowiring doesn't work. How do I register these with my context?

---

**EDIT:** for the autowiring, I have noted Sean Patrick Floyd response here: [How to get beans created by FactoryBean spring managed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970297/how-to-get-beans-created-by-factorybean-spring-managed?rq=1) but this still doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this solution in the end, but I am not sure whether its the best or not:

```
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(new BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
            ConstructorArgumentValues cav = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
            cav.addGenericArgumentValue(MyClass.class);

            RootBeanDefinition bean = new RootBeanDefinition(MyFactoryBean.class, cav, null);
            AnnotationBeanNameGenerator generator = new AnnotationBeanNameGenerator();

            registry.registerBeanDefinition(generator.generateBeanName(bean, registry), bean);
        }

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException { }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the following discussion: [How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring)

I believe that this is exactly what you need: use `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`.

Comment: How do I register that `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` with the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext `?

Comment: You should create your bean that will live in Spring context, inject `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` into it and use it to create other instances programmatically. These instances will be autowired if you use code similar to one that I referenced.